# Java constructor not called

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, super

I have a class called Queen, that is a subclass of Ant. The constructor for Queen takes in parameters, and passes those on to Ants constructor, plus additional specifics for a queen. Now, that is how it is supposed to work. However I have found that the Ant constructor is never being called. Am I missing something?

```
public class Queen extends Ant
{
    public Queen(int width, int height, Square[][] grid)
    {
        super(0, 0, width, height);
        //grid[locationHeight][locationWidth].addQueen(this);
    }
}
```

Ant constructor (I had some println statements in here, but they were never called when constructing a queen):

```
public Ant(int id, int type, int width, int height)
    {
        antID = id;
        antType = type;
        isAlive = true;
        width = width / 2;
        height = height / 2;
        setLocation(width, height);
        if (antType == 0)
        {
            lifeSpan = 73000;
        }
        else
        {
            lifeSpan = 3650;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us the code you use to instantiate the `Queen` class.

Comment: I strongly suspect you've just misdiagnosed this. The Ant constructor really *will* be called.

Comment: Does it reach the Queen constructor?

Comment: The compiler would enforce that Ant's constructor was called, why do you think it isn't being called?

Comment: Unless you have other constructors in Ant/Queen, Ant's constructor will be called.

Comment: if `Ant` class only contains parametric constructor the compiler wouldn't let you run the program until creating default constructor.

Comment: I have added println statements to both the queen constructor and the ant constructor. When instantiating the queen, the println statements in that constructor print to the terminal, but those in the ant constructor don't.

Comment: @Nick can you please show us the your queen class :)

Comment: What you describe is not possible, if you are invoking the code as you say you are. Try to recompile everything.

Comment: Provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so we can replicate what you're seeing.  If you describe bizarre exceptional behavior, and don't provide code to reproduce it, you're going to be met with lots of incredulity.

Answer (score 3):

In Java constructors *always* calls its super constructor. Either it implicitly calls the no arg parent constructor or you're specifying a constructor to call (That's why you have to call a super constructor if your super class doesn't specify a default constructor).

From the [java specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7):

> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class Object, then the constructor body implicitly begins with a superclass constructor invocation "super();", an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments.

To your code sample: without the full code it's hard to tell what's going on, but if Queen extends Ant, and the shown constructors are the only ones, it *should* work.

Answer (score 2):

You are not instantiating your Queen object using the Queen(int,int,Square[][]) constructor, you must be using another constructor or not instantiating a Queen at all.

Comment: I deleted all my compiled .class files and then recompiled. Seems to have resolved the issue.